# Parameters not being passed into rdlc reports

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am trying to display rdlc reports in c# windows aplication.I am passing parameters to the report by this code-named

```
 localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { new ReportParameter("JobC", m) });
```

I have defined this parameter in the report also. But the parameter is not being passed into the report and the database table is not getting filtered. The first record, though, is being displayed., how to solve this error?

Comment: Can you provide more code? How do you run your report? What do you use to create those reports? M$ SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Builder 3.0?

Comment: Check the accepted answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1177290.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to the rdlc Design view 
2.on the report data view (On the left) select parameters 
3.Right click Add 
4.set the name (best you Check Allow blank and allow null value)click OK

5.add the textfiled value OR select one from your tablix,right click and select Expression
6.set the expression e.g

```
=Parameters!title.Value
```

7.In your form that contains your report view add the following lines for a single parameter

```
ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("title", title); this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp });
           });
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

8.for multiple parameters

```
 ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("title", title);
 ReportParameter rps  = new ReportParameter("expense", totalExpense.ToString());
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new R`enter code here`eportParameter[] { rp });
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rps });
 reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```